# Is it possible to change a 'relaxing length' of edges for 8 node hexaedral element in 3d FEM

Tags: finite-element-method, solid-mechanics

I am using 3D FEM with 8 node brick element to model a certain type of growth/expansion, which is not a plastic deformation. First, I apply a pressure/load and I get displacement and new position of nodes and calculate stress/strain. Next, I would like to change the 'edges' relaxing length (different edges by different factors) of an 8 node hexaedral element. Such change in relaxing length would be due to addition of a new material, resulting in expansion of a mesh. My question is, whether in such a model I can calculate sort of relaxing length for a brick element edges after application of pressure and consequently change it to get new nodal positions? I can imaging doing so for e.g. 1D string, but I am not sure if it makes any sense for 3D hexaedral element.

I would be grateful for any helpful suggestion/comments

Denis